# How would i check the boolean variable in main so my do-while loop goes through the three functions?

Tags: c++, string, vector, project

Okay so my problem is I can't seem to find or think of anything that will go into the while argument that will check all three functions to see if each one is false please help! That is my problem!

```
class Validate
{
public: 
    Validate(string);
     Validate();
    bool checkLength();
    bool checkSpaces();
    bool checkUpper();
    //bool checkUpper(char);
private:
    string password;
    static const int LEN = 5;

};
Validate::Validate()
{

}
Validate::Validate(string pass)
{
    pass = password;

}
bool Validate:: checkLength()
{
        if (password.length() < LEN)
        {
            cout << "Password is not 5 characters." << "  please try again..." << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;

}
bool Validate::checkSpaces()
{
    if (password.find(' ') != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "Password can not have any spaces " << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
bool Validate::checkUpper()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!isupper(password[i]))
        {
            cout << "Password must have at least one uppercase" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }



}
```

Main file

```
//DISPLAY 8.9 Using a Vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "c:\Users\barta\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project 7\Project 7\Validate.h"

int main( )
{

    vector<string> data;
    string firstName, lastName, login, userName, password;
    Validate c;
    bool check;
    firstName = "1";

    cout << "Enter your first name.\n";
    getline(cin, firstName);
    while (firstName != "0")
    {

        cout << "Enter your last name.\n";
        getline(cin, lastName);
        do
        {

            cout << "Enter a password.\n";
            getline(cin, password);
            //password = c.checkLength();
            //password = c.checkSpaces();
            c.checkUpper();

        } while (false);

        lastName = lastName.substr(0, 5);

        userName = firstName.at(0) + lastName;
        login = userName + ", " + password;
        data.push_back(login);

        cout << "Enter your first name.\n";
        getline(cin, firstName);
    }

    cout << "  Login data entered \n" << endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "  " << data.at(i) << endl;
        }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly unclear, but I think you're looking for:

```
 bool flag;

 do
 {
        // All your existing code is here...

        Validate c{password};

        flag = c.checkLength() || c.checkSpaces() || c.checkUpper();

 } while (flag);
```

Your `Validate` class's constructor takes the password as a parameter, so you have to construct the object after the password is read, and not at the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: I tried that and the loop thinks the password is incorrect

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. I see at least one bug in your checkUpper() method.

Comment: Yeah the debugger says  "Validate::checkUpper': not all control paths return a value"

Comment: @BartAlen Well, that error message is pretty clear, isn't it? Check that function and provide a return value for every possible path taken in that function.

Comment: Alright i figured out the error but i still need help with the do-while loop

Comment: You were already told: use the debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, in order to observe the step-by-step logic. At the point where the observed logic diverges from your expectations, you will have your answer. If you still need additional help, [ask your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: There's more to a debugger than pinpointing errors. The debugger lets you step through your code, one line at a time, and to examine the values of all variables, at any point. This makes it possible to understand the difference between what the code is actually doing, and what you expect it to do. Learning how to use a debugger is a required skill for anyone who expects to have a career as a C++ developer.